# nodejs skipping single quote from json key in output

Tags: node.js

I see a very weird problem when json when used in nodejs, it is skipping single quote from revision key . I want to pass this json as input to node request module and since single quote is missing from 'revision' key so it is not taking as valid json input. Could someone help how to retain it so that I can use it. I have tried multiple attempts but not able to get it correct.

What did I try ?

console.log(jsondata)

```
jsondata = {
            'splits': {
                'os-name': 'ubuntu',
                'platform-version': 'os',
                'traffic-percent': 100,
                'revision': 'master'
            }
        }
```

Expected :-

```
{ splits:
  { 'os-name': 'ubuntu',
   'platform-version': 'os',
   'traffic-percent': 100,
    'revision': 'master' 
 } 
}
```

But in actual output single quote is missing from revision key :-

```
{ splits:
   { 'os-name': 'ubuntu',
     'platform-version': 'os',
     'traffic-percent': 100,
       revision: 'master' 
   } 
}
```

Run 2 :- Tried below code this also produce same thing.

```
 data = JSON.stringify(jsondata)
 result = JSON.parse(data)
 console.log(result)
```

Run 3:-  Used another way to achieve it

```
jsondata = {}
temp = {} 
splits = []
        temp['revision'] = 'master',
            temp['os-name'] = 'ubuntu'
        temp['platform-version'] = 'os'
        temp['traffic-percent'] = 100
        splits.push(temp)

jsondata['splits'] = splits
console.log(jsondata)
```

Run 4: tries replacing single quotes to double quotes

Run 5 : Change the order of revision line

Comment: In JS it doesn't matter whether you declare the keys of the object with single quotes, double quotes or no quotes at all. What are you trying to achieve in general? What are you doing with the result and why do you need it with(out) quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is supposed to happen. The quotes are kept only if the object key it’s not a valid JavaScript identifier. In your example, the **'splits'** & **'revision'** don't have a dash in their name, so they are the only ones with the quotes removed.

You shouldn't receive any error using this object - if you do, update this post mentioning the scenario and the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should note that *JSON* and *JavaScript* are not the same things.

JSON is a format where all keys and values are surrounded by *double quotes* ("key" and "value"). A JSON string is produced by `JSON.stringify`, and is required by `JSON.parse`.

A JavaScript object has very similar syntax to the JSON file format, but is more flexible - the values can be surrounded by double quotes *or* single quotes, and the keys can have no quotes at all as long as they are valid JavaScript identifiers. If the keys have spaces, dashes, or other non-valid characters, then they need to be surrounded by single quotes or double quotes.

If you need your string to be valid JSON, generate it with `JSON.stringify`. If it's OK for it to be just valid JavaScript, then it's already fine - it does not matter whether the quotes are there or not.

If, for some reason, you need some imaginary third option (perhaps you are interacting with an API where someone has written their own custom string parser, and they are demanding that all keys are surrounded by single quotes?) you will probably need to write your own little string generator.